# Get dates during fullcalendar initializing

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using eventSources method to initialize FullCalendar jQuery plugin.

eventSources: [
    initEvents(visibleStartDate, visibleEndDate)
]

where initEvents is and ajax call to jsp page that returns json object representing events to be rendered.  It works great but now I'd like to fetch the event only for the dates visible on calendar.  I read in documentation that I could use visStart and visEnd on View object to get the start and end day of the calendar, however I don't know how to get that information at the time I initialize my eventSources.  Is there a way?  Thank you in advance for your responses.

Eric

Comment: I think I figured out my own question: The "start" and "end" parameters are added automatically by fullcalendar.  More details here:   http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: Please post the answer, maybe other people will have the same problem in the future.

Comment: In my JSP page I retrieved start date like so:String start = request.getParameter("start");
Date startDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(start)*1000);  I'll post full code once I am sure it all works :)

Comment: Ok but this is a comment not an answer ;)

Comment: Will add full answer once 8 hour 'quarantine' for posting answers to own questions expires.  Cheers, Eric

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that fullcalendar plugin will add start and end HTTP parameters when calendar sources are fetched externally. Full details are described in documentation here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

My code (mix of javascript, JSP, JSF):

1. FullCalendal initialization:

```
page.view.calendar.fullCalendar(
{ 
....
eventSources: [ 
page.control.initEventSources(#{sessionBean.myCalendar.calendarConfgIdNbr},'Approved'),         
page.control.initCalendarHolidays(#{sessionBean.myCalendar.calendarConfgIdNbr})], 
.... 
});
```

2.  My javascript function:
    page.control.initEventSources:

```
var page = { 
            control : { 
                initEventSources : function(calConfId, status) {
                    return { 
                        url: '/oceportal/tom/data/bookings.jsp', 
                        type: 'POST', 
                        data: { calConfId: calConfId, bookingStatus: status, loggedInId: "#{sessionBean.loggedInId}", },
                        success: function(data) { },
                        error: function() { alert('there was an error while fetching events!'); },
                        color: 'none', 
                        textColor: page.colorConfig[status] 
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

1. My JSP snippet (to retrieve first and last visible day):

   ```
   String start = request.getParameter("start"); 
   Date startDt = new Date(Long.parseLong(start)*1000); 
   String end = request.getParameter("end"); 
   Date endDt = new Date(Long.parseLong(end)*1000);
   ```

   Hope it helps someone.